# Empty the queue using a scoped_thread_pool Pool

Tags: multithreading, rust, threadpool

I've been using [scoped_thread_pool::Pool](https://docs.rs/scoped-thread-pool/latest/scoped_thread_pool/struct.Pool.html). Typically my pool size will be 8 (number of virtual cores in my machine). But I'm submitting hundreds of threads in the blink of an eye, most of which then wait. The first test in each each thread, when it runs, is to see whether a global variable has been set to curtail the whole parallel process.

This works pretty fast. If the flag is set these hundreds of threads are started and immediately stopped when they run that test.

But it seems to me that it would be better to drain the queue actively the first time this stop flag is detected. I found there is a `struct` `WaitGroup` in this crate, but it's not clear to me how you get a reference to it, or indeed whether it can be drained.

`WaitGroup` has a method `poison`, but this says "Poison the WaitGroup so all joining threads panic." This isn't quite what I want ideally. I want to empty the queue.

Comment: It's quite possible that the crate you are using simply doesn't support the feature of clearing up an already established queue. In that case you can fork the crate to add that functionality or switch to one that has it already. Another thing to consider is whether your current code is actually that bad - "hundreds" of jobs which check the flag at the very beginning will drain very very fast.

Comment: To understand: do you want to be able to support cancelling the threads even in the middle of the computation?

Comment: @user4815162342. Points taken, thanks. @ChayimFriedman: yes. Simply put: if a user command arrives saying "stop that parallel processing command ASAP", I'd ideally like the threads which are queued on the `Pool` but which haven't been run yet never to start being run at all. I believe it is not uncommon to be able to do that with queues for thread pools. Looks like this crate may not offer that.

Comment: It is impossible to kill a thread in Rust (for soundness reasons, IIRC). It is possible that the threadpool implementation you're using (or another) will offer an option to cancel jobs in the queue, but why won't you take the conventional approach with a shared `AtomicBool` that is checked periodically?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman. Um, that's exactly what I'm doing. I hoped I had made it clear by now that what I'm suggesting is **not starting** a bunch of threads. Not starting a thread is not the same as trying to kill one, which you obviously can't do in Rust.

Comment: @mikerodent I wasn't able to find a crate that implements this functionality, unfortunately (there is one but without scoped pool support). It is fairly trivial to add, however, you only need to check an `AtomicBool` every time you spawn a job.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for looking. Yes, in fact I've done a bit of testing and, with about 300 threads added to the queue (and a pool size of 8, i.e. number of virtual cores), I'm finding that it actually takes as long as 800 ms to shut down the pool, i.e. with each remaining thread being started and stopped immediately (because of the `AtomicBool`). So yes, I may well see if I can work out a modification (fork). Maybe instead I should implement a "pre-queue" though in my code: but in practice that'd be quite complex, I think.